# How to better merge .gz files?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I want to merge two files ending with .gz. I have tried two ways among others. For the first way, I directly concatenated the files using cat; for the other way, I first decompressed each file through gunzip, and then concatenated the decompressed files before compressing again using gzip. Interestingly, I found that the resulting files vary in size. Could anyone answer my puzzle here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your puzzlement? Of course they're different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder which way is better since the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is which is better, then concatenating is faster, but recompressing will give you better compression. So it depends on how you define "better".